# Assign a new column to dataframe based on data from current row and previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns of data called level 1 event and level 2 event. 
Both are columns of 1s and zeros.

```
lev_1 lev_2 lev_2_&_lev_1
0    1    0      0
1    0    0      0
2    1    0      0
3    1    1      1
4    1    0      0
```

`col['lev2_&_lev_1] = 1` if `lev_2` of current row and `lev_1` of previous row are both 1. 
I have achieved this by using for loop.

```
i = 1  
while i < a.shape[0]:
    if a['lev_1'].iloc[i - 1] == 1 &  a['lev_2'].iloc[i] == 1:
        a['lev_2_&_lev_1'].iloc[i] = 1
    i += 1
```

I wanted to know a computationally efficient way to do this because my original df is very big.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` and `.shift()`:

```
df['lev_2_&_lev_1'] = np.where(df['lev_2'].eq(1) & df['lev_1'].shift().eq(1), 1, 0)

   lev_1  lev_2  lev_2_&_lev_1
0      1      0              0
1      0      0              0
2      1      0              0
3      1      1              1
4      1      0              0
```

---

**Explanation**

- `df['lev_2'].eq(1)`: checks if current row is equal to 1
- `df['lev_1'].shift().eq(1)`: checks if previous row is equal to 1
- `np.where(condition, 1, 0)`: if condition is `True` return `1` else `0`

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
(df['lev_2'] & df['lev_1'].shift()).astype(int)
```